# AutoComplete with name and number as in native sms app Android

Tags: android, android-contacts, autocompletetextview

I want to add an `AutoCompleteTextView` in my app and search contacts by name and number as done in the native SMS app with android. I have looked on the internet and tried quite a few things, but I want my application to display it exactly as the android SMS app. Here is the code I am trying that searches only by `Display_Name`.

```
public class MakePayment extends Activity {
    private AutoCompleteTextView mAuto;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.makepayment);

        mAuto = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextViewTest);
        ContentResolver content = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = content.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                PEOPLE_PROJECTION, null, null, null);

        ContactListAdapter adapter = new ContactListAdapter(this, cursor);
        mAuto.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

     public static class ContactListAdapter extends CursorAdapter implements Filterable {
            public ContactListAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
                super(context, c);
                mContent = context.getContentResolver();
            }

            @Override
            public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
                 final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                    final TextView view = (TextView) inflater.inflate(
                            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, parent, false);
                    view.setText(cursor.getString(2));
                    return view;
            }        

            @Override
            public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
                ((TextView) view).setText(cursor.getString(2));

            }

            @Override
            public String convertToString(Cursor cursor) {
                return cursor.getString(2);
            }

            @Override
            public Cursor runQueryOnBackgroundThread(CharSequence constraint) {
                if (getFilterQueryProvider() != null) {
                    return getFilterQueryProvider().runQuery(constraint);
                }

                StringBuilder buffer = null;
                String[] args = null;
                if (constraint != null) {
                    buffer = new StringBuilder();
                buffer.append("UPPER(");
                buffer.append(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
                buffer.append(") GLOB ?");
                    args = new String[] { constraint.toString().toUpperCase() + "*" };
                }

                return mContent.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, PEOPLE_PROJECTION,
                        buffer == null ? null : buffer.toString(), args,
                        null);
            }



            private ContentResolver mContent;           
        }

     private static final String[] PEOPLE_PROJECTION = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
        };

}
```

How do I search by phone numbers as well? And then display it like this:
[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37724842/auto-suggest-contact-numbers-from-phone-contacts-android

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have already done something similar in the past that's what I've done:

**note:** you will get Autocompletion after taping two character

The layout file uses an AutoCompleteView, its basically an EditText with a dropdown list that appears as you type in it. The .xml file in youe example looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:orientation="vertical"

android:layout_width="fill_parent"

android:layout_height="fill_parent"

>

<AutoCompleteTextView

android:id="@+id/mmWhoNo"

android:layout_width="fill_parent"

android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:hint="To...."

>

</AutoCompleteTextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

To create the custom view used in the AutoCompleteView you have to declare another .xml file called custcontview.xml and it will looks like this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ccontName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textColor="#A5000000"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ccontNo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/ccontName"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textColor="#A5000000"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ccontType"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/ccontNo"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:textColor="#A5000000"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

now In your Activity:

```
public class ContactActivity extends Activity {

    private ArrayList<Map<String, String>> mPeopleList;

    private SimpleAdapter mAdapter;
    private AutoCompleteTextView mTxtPhoneNo;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mPeopleList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        PopulatePeopleList();
        mTxtPhoneNo = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.mmWhoNo);

        mAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mPeopleList, R.layout.custcontview ,new String[] { "Name", "Phone" , "Type" }, new int[] { R.id.ccontName, R.id.ccontNo, R.id.ccontType });

        mTxtPhoneNo.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        }

    public void PopulatePeopleList()
    {

    mPeopleList.clear();

    Cursor people = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    while (people.moveToNext())
    {
    String contactName = people.getString(people.getColumnIndex(
    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

    String contactId = people.getString(people.getColumnIndex(
    ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
    String hasPhone = people.getString(people.getColumnIndex(
    ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

    if ((Integer.parseInt(hasPhone) > 0))
    {

    // You know have the number so now query it like this
    Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
    null,
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId,
    null, null);
    while (phones.moveToNext()) {

    //store numbers and display a dialog letting the user select which.
    String phoneNumber = phones.getString(
    phones.getColumnIndex(
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

    String numberType = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));

    Map<String, String> NamePhoneType = new HashMap<String, String>();

    NamePhoneType.put("Name", contactName);
    NamePhoneType.put("Phone", phoneNumber);

    if(numberType.equals("0"))
    NamePhoneType.put("Type", "Work");
    else
    if(numberType.equals("1"))
    NamePhoneType.put("Type", "Home");
    else if(numberType.equals("2"))
    NamePhoneType.put("Type",  "Mobile");
    else
    NamePhoneType.put("Type", "Other");

    //Then add this map to the list.
    mPeopleList.add(NamePhoneType);
    }
    phones.close();
    }
    }
    people.close();

    startManagingCursor(people);
    }
    }
```

Don't forget to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>
```

in your manifest

Comment: works perfectly fine! Thank you. Just one question: When i select a particular contact, the AutoCompleteTextView is something like this{Name=ABC, Type=XYZ, Phone=xxx-xxx-xxxx}. how can i get it to just the name?

Comment: did you get any solution about only showing a contact name or number?

Comment: Add a onItemClickListener for the AutoCompleteTextView instead of having it as a seperate function.......    mTxtPhoneNo.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View arg1, int index,
                 long arg3) {
             Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) av.getItemAtPosition(index);

             String name  = map.get("Name");
             String number = map.get("Phone");
             mTxtPhoneNo.setText(""+name+"<"+number+">");

         }

     }); and it will work

Comment: I am trying to adapt this to a `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` but it's not allowing multiple entries. Do mind giving me some help? Here is the link to my original question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22443791/multiautocompletetextview-with-contacts-phone-numbers. The description has evolved to be your present answer.

Comment: @K_Anas hi, i used above approach, but if i gave space into letters than it stop showing suggestions? Any idea how to resolve this? Thanks

Comment: `startManagingCursor()` is deprectaed. Whats the alternate?

Comment: @K_Anas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37724842/auto-suggest-contact-numbers-from-phone-contacts-android   help me

Answer (score 0):

The AutoCompleteTextView was completed using the code by @K_Anas. Since it returns a (key, value) pair, I used the following to display only the number of the selected item:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int index, long arg) {
    Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) av.getItemAtPosition(index);
    Iterator<String> myVeryOwnIterator = map.keySet().iterator();
          while(myVeryOwnIterator.hasNext()) {
            String key=(String)myVeryOwnIterator.next();
            String value=(String)map.get(key);
            mTxtPhoneNo.setText(value);
        }               
    }
});
```

Things achieved in this question:

- AutoCompleteTextView to load contacts in the format just as in the
  picture in the question above.
- Setting Text as the phone number of    the selected value.

Comment: i am also facing the same problem like you, when i click on any of the number from the list i am getting something like this. `{Name=John, Type=Mobile, Phone=1-234-456-7890}`