# Predictive text implementataion for android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I want to provide predictive text for auto-completion of words as user types in android in built-in application such as sms,contact. 
But i don,t want to use dictionary feature provided by android .I have of dictionary of words and i want to provide user with predictive words from that dictionary.
So how can i make my dictionary available to user.

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147311/autocomplete-with-name-and-number-as-in-native-sms-app-android