# Contact name and phone number in an EditText - filtered typing

Tags: android, filter, android-edittext, phone-number, contact-list

What I want to do is to have an EditText, there I can type some name (so that appears a filtered list with the names that correspond to what I have typed so far). Finally I choose a contact. The EditText shall display the name that I had chosen, but send a message (sms) to the number that corresponds to the contact chosen.

Here is my code, which is not complete: 
Of course I have some settings also in the AndroidManifest file..

public class SendSMSActivity extends Activity {

```
Button buttonSend;
EditText textPhoneNo;
EditText textSMS;
String sms ="";
ListAdapter lAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sendsms);

    buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);
    textPhoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPhoneNo);        
    textPhoneNo.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String srchName = textPhoneNo.getText().toString();
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                    null,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER
                            + " = 1 AND "
                            + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
                            + " like " + "'" + srchName + "%'",
                    null,
                    "UPPER(" + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
                            + ") ASC");
            startManagingCursor(cursor);

            Load(cursor);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    textSMS = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSMS);

    sms = MainActivityClass.tempSms.toString();
    Log.d("SendSMSActivity", " sms text = " + sms);
    textSMS.setText(sms);
    textSMS.setVisibility(EditText.VISIBLE);

    buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String phoneNo = textPhoneNo.getText().toString();
            //String sms = textSMS.getText().toString();


            try {
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, sms, null, null);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "SMS faild, please try again later!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
});

}
```

}

Comment: autocompletetextview have you tried this?

Comment: @Elior So far I have tried to retrieve the names at least, but I am not really sure how to use the cursor and the listAdapter. I have got lost on my way.

Comment: @Raghunandan I have tried with addTextChangeListener and TextWatcher! I am newbee, so I am not really sure how to put it together to get it work.

Comment: @Diana can you post your code? it will be more helpful to see what is wrong

Comment: Ok I think it will be more easier with the way I suggest.. and more efficient.. in my way (on my answer) , first you read all the contacts and save it into a list.. then when the text is changed you display the contacts which contains the characters you type

Comment: please see the link :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147311/autocomplete-with-name-and-number-as-in-native-sms-app-android

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what have you tried but for this moment I will give some points of thoughts:

1. Create your own Contact class which have name and phone members.
2. Iterate with the cursor in your contact list and for each iterate create new Contact with
   the name and phone your received from the contact list.
3. when you create the new contact store it into a list (I mean list like this : `List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>(); )`
4. this list will be stored on your list adapter
5. when you type on the editText check if there is some contact which contains the same chracters